# Java: generic classes explanation of code

Tags: java, generics, syntax

Coming from C++, some Java code looks very strange to me. Can someone explain to me what the following code fragment is supposed to do?

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private static <T> Class<T> getGenericType(Class<?> clz) {
    return (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) clz.getGenericSuperclass())
            .getActualTypeArguments()[0];
}
```

I read this in a response to another question ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35946321/java-primitive-counterpart-of-byte-integer-long-etc-in-template)) which I am trying to understand in detail.

Comment: it returns type of the generic, so if you pass `ArrayList<String>` - it will return `String`

Comment: Honestly I think it's just there for the `@SuppressWarnings`.  This code doesn't actually do anything except call `getActualTypeArguments()`.  The generics are all essentially removed from the actual run-time code.

Comment: "another question" which other question?

Comment: @Lashane you can't pass this method an ArrayList; it's argument type is `Class`  You could pass in `ArrayList<String>.class` though.

Comment: @markspace There's no such thing as `ArrayList<String>.class`, only `ArrayList.class`.

Comment: Yeah you're right.  Stupid Java.  It's really kind of a pain that you can't express generic class types easily in Java.

Comment: @markspace of course you should pass class object, like `new ArrayList<String>(){}.getClass()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have a generic class `Foo`, like so:

```
public class Foo<T> {
    T myVar;
}
```

In a lot of ways, this is like a template in C++. `T` is some type, could be `String`, could be `Integer`, could be `Object`, could be `SomeTypeYouveNeverHeardOf`, all depending on the code that uses `Foo`, not the code inside `Foo`.

And a subclass of it, `Bar`:

```
public class Bar extends Foo<String> {}
```

`Bar` is not a generic class, though it uses one as its superclass. It specifies that, for all instances of `Bar`, the type variable `T` is actually `String`, so the `myVar` instance variable it inherits from `Foo` will always be a `String`.

Now with that setup out of the way, let's turn to your method.

First, it takes a `Class` object as its parameter. Let's say we call it with `Bar.class`. The first thing your method does is call `getGenericSuperclass()` on it, which retrieves an object representing its superclass - `Foo<String>`.

Now, `getGenericSuperclass()` is declared to return a `Type` object, but the code is assuming that the class passed in has generic inheritance (that is, that it extends something like `Foo<String>` rather than just `Foo`), and in that case it will actually return a `ParameterizedType`. So it type casts it and calls `getActualTypeArguments()` to retrieve what the type arguments are - the `String` part of `extends Foo<String>`. This is returned as an array because in the more general case it could be dealing with things like `extends ComplexObject<String, Integer, Foo, Object>`.

Having acquired a size 1 array of `Class` objects, it then returns the array's first member. In this example, the returned value is `String.class`.

Answer (score 1):

What this method does on my system, now that I test it, is throw an exception at runtime.  So I guess what it does is "nothing useful."

```
public class GenericTest
{

   public static void main( String[] args )
   {
      ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<>();
      System.out.println( getGenericType( al.getClass() ) );
   }

   @SuppressWarnings( "unchecked" )
   private static <T> Class<T> getGenericType( Class<?> clz )
   {
      return (Class<T>) ( (ParameterizedType) clz.getGenericSuperclass() )
              .getActualTypeArguments()[0];  // line 28
   }
}

run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.TypeVariableImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.Class
    at quicktest.GenericTest.getGenericType(GenericTest.java:28)
    at quicktest.GenericTest.main(GenericTest.java:21)
C:\Users\Brenden\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 2 seconds)
```

Comment: That's because you're passing it `ArrayList.class` (retrieved in a slightly roundabout way), which doesn't use generics in its inheritance.

Comment: What class type should I be passing in?

Comment: Anything where the `extends` clause includes generic angle brackets. An anonymous subclass of `ArrayList`, such as @Lashane` points out, should work (note the `{}`).